# run kubernetes containers without minikube or etc

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, orchestration

I want to just run an nginx-server on kubernetes with the help of

```
kubectl run nginx-image --image nginx
```

but the error was thrown:

```
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:

  1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config
```

I then ran

```
kubectl run nginx-image --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config --image nginx
```

again thrown:

```
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:

  1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config
```

*minikube start solves the problem but it is taking resources...*

**I just want to ask How can I run kubectl without minikube (or other such solutions) being started? Please tell me if it not possible**

when I run `kubectl get pods`, I get two pods instead I just want one and I know it is possible since I had seen in some video tutorials.

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubectl is a command-line tool and it is responsible for communicating with Minikube. Kubectl allows you to run commands against Minikube. You can use Kubectl to deploy applications, inspect and manage resources, and view logs. When you execute this command

```
kubectl run nginx-image --image nginx
```

kubectl tries to connect to minikube and sends your request(run Nginx) to it. So if you stop minikube, kubectl can't communicate. So minikube is responsible to run Nginx and kubectl is just responsible to tell Minikube to run Nginx

Answer (score 1):

I mean you need to install Kubernetes in order to use it. It’s not magic. If minikube isn’t to your liking there are many installers, try Docker Desktop or k3d.

Comment: OK I have minikube installed. I can run kubectl command from my terminal. So I thought I could just run an image with k8s using kubectl command only, without starting minikube and VM. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Kubernetes is running inside the VM. If the VM is not running, Kubernetes is not running.